# Xamarin IOS Navigation with TableView

Tags: c#, uitableview, xamarin, uinavigationcontroller

I am sure this is probably a very simple solution, but I am quite new to xamarin and c# in general. I have created a tableview, and when a cell in that view is pressed I want it to navigate to a new view, named SecondViewController(). I have the following class in my ViewController.cs

```
     public void changeview()
    {

           SecondViewController controller = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SecondViewController") as SecondViewController;
        this.NavigationController.PushViewController(controller, true);
    }
```

Then in my TableSource.cs class, I have the following code to call changeview()

```
   public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

        ViewController view = new ViewController();
        view.changeview();
        tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);
    }
```

I get no errors when it compiles, but when it runs I get an error on the following code

```
   SecondViewController controller = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SecondViewController") as SecondViewController;
```

which reads

```
  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

why does this not work? if I use this same code within a button class it works great, to test to make sure I was calling the class correctly I changed the code within changeview() to a UIAlertView and when a cell was pressed the alertview worked. I am not sure where to go from here, possibly there is a better method for changing views for this purpose? any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
       SecondViewController controller = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SecondViewController") as SecondViewController;
```

Do you used Storyboard Id for "SecondViewController". If not goto stroyboard add storyboard Id to your SecondViewController

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a global reference or access to the current active navigation controller of your application in order to make a push.

What you can do is to create an instance of an `AppDelegate` and set the Navigation Controller to a variable.

In your AppDelegate.cs

```
[Register ("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    //application layer declarations
    public UINavigationController navCtrl { get; set; }
    /*
    .
    .  the rest of the codes
    .
    .*/
}
```

In your ViewController.cs (First view) or the root view controller where you instantiated the navigation controller:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad() {
    AppDelegate appD = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate;

    // assign the UINavigationController to the variable being used to push
    // assuming that you have already initialised or instantiated a UINavigationController
    appD.navCtrl = this.NavigationController; // Your UINavigation controller should be here
    /*
    .
    . the rest of the codes
    .
    */
}
```

In your TableSource.cs Class.

```
private AppDelegate appD = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate;

public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath){
    SecondViewController secondView = UIStoryboard.FromName ("Main", null).InstantiateViewController ("SecondViewController") as SecondViewController;
    appD.navCtrl.PushViewController (secondView, true);
}
```

This should be able to do what you want.

Comment: I just tried this code and it is now giving me "An unhandled exception occured." and I have no idea why. in your someFunction() should there be anymore code after those two lines, or is that all that should be within the function? Should anything be calling this function? thank you very much for the reply!

Comment: Can you update your code sample in the question and include your First view controller where you used your navigation controller? In fact, have you initialised a UINavigationController object somewhere? In my example, someFunction() should be your own function like `viewDidLoad()` . I have updated my example to eliminate confusions.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a reference of your ViewController in your TableSource.cs class as

```
public ViewController ParentController{ get; set;}
```

When initializing the data source,

```
tableClassObject.ParentController = this;
```

In Row Selected, it should be

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);
        ParentController.changeview();
    }
```

This is simplest solution.